# What character encoding is this?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

I'm interfacing with an Oracle DB, which has some messed up encoding (ASCII7 according to the db properties, but actually encodes Korean characters).

When I get some of the Korean strings from the resultSet, and look at the bytes, it turns out that they correspond exactly to this file (I found by googling some of the byte sequences): http://211.115.85.9/files/raw3.txt

Kinda spooky, as it seems to be the ONLY thing on the internet that has anything about this particular encoding...

The file, when viewed with EditPlus3, shows me 3 columns.

The first column is an alphabetical listing of Korean characters.  The second is the strange encoding I'm finding from looking at the Java strings passed from the Oracle DB.  The third one is UTF8.

I'm trying to figure out what the middle column is encoded in.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

(I really don't want to have to actually read from this file every time I need to call a DB...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is EUC-KR (or a similar) encoded data, interpreted as another 1-byte encoding (ISO-8859-1 or similar) and encoded using UTF-8.

In other words: it's ill-encoded data, but might be salvagable:

```java
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { (byte) 0xc2, (byte) 0xb0, (byte) 0xc2, (byte) 0xa1 };
String str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
bytes = str.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
str = new String(bytes, "EUC-KR");
System.out.println(str);
```

This prints 가 on my system.

I've found [this PDF file](https://web.archive.org/web/20130909072935/http://brianhitchcock.net/Oracle_items_for_website/PDF/BookReview--NoCOUG200402--TheCaseoftheMissingKanji.pdf) which explains the problem (and how it happend) in more detail.

Comment: Amazing.  You, sir, are AWESOME.

Comment: The PDF link is broken. I believe this is the archived version of the same PDF: https://web.archive.org/web/20130909072935/http://brianhitchcock.net/Oracle_items_for_website/PDF/BookReview--NoCOUG200402--TheCaseoftheMissingKanji.pdf

Comment: @AndreiCalinescu: yes, that's the one, I updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

It is UTF-8 encoding:

```
가 c2b0c2a1 eab080
각 c2b0c2a2 eab081
간 c2b0c2a3 eab084
갇 c2b0c2a4 eab087
...
```

I don't know the meaning of the middle column, but the third column is a hex-representation of the Hangul in the first row.

Watch the file with a hex editor, this may help.

Good luck! :)

Comment: I.. er... sorry, I knew that already.  I'm interested pretty much only in the second column.

Comment: i found a korean site that specifically highlights `가` as `b0a1` on its grid for `EUR-KR`. Granted, it's only a tiny subset of the syllables, but gives an idea how the mapping worked (`https://coding-factory.tistory.com/810`) (I think `unicode.org` has the full mapping file)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little script and decoded the middle column of the first two lines brute force.

The following four results are Hangul but I'm not sure, if they make sense:

```
utf_16_be => 슰슡 슰슢
johab => 춿춰 춿춱
euc_kr => 째징 째짖
cp949 => 째징 째짖
```

I hope that helped. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: :D appreciate the effort, but the first column is the actual corresponding korean character (`각`).  The second column is an unknown encoding which I am trying to identify, and I know it encodes a single Korean character.  (Yes, it appears to be a 32-bit encoding scheme.)