# youtube data api, foreign language support

Tags: python, api, youtube

I'm trying to gather metadata from a youtube channel using python via youtube data api-v3.
I've managed to get data in json format but the texts like titles, descriptions, comments etc are in Korean language and they are shown as

ex : "title": "\ud55c \uc5ec\ub984\ubc24\uc758 \uafc8",

Is there a way to set encoding for specific feature/keys?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/i18nLanguages/list

The above seems to be the way to solve the problem, but I am new to api and I do not know how to apply it... can anyone give me an example or a link? so I can try myself?

or is there a way to decode back to original language? from the broken language output?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5855947/4092887) - or search `korean string encoding` or see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44599288/4092887) or search any of these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=korean+python+string). Let us know if that works or if you found the solution.